# RMI over SSL, How do I integrate truststore and keystore into application?

Tags: java, authentication, ssl, rmi

I followed the tutorial at [SSL/TLS-based RMI Socket Factories](https://blogs.oracle.com/lmalventosa/entry/using_the_ssl_tls_based)

And I have been able to generate a keystore and trustore.
For the moment only the Server authenticates itself.

When I put the keystore and trustore file in the root folder of my Eclipse project and I launch manually in windows console (or adding VM arguments in Eclipse) :

```
$ java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=truststore -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=trustword RmiRegistry &

$ java -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=keystore -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=password HelloImpl &

$ java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=truststore -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=trustword HelloClient
```

Everything works correctly. Now if I want to send my application (it is for an assignment). Where can I put the trustore and keystore and how can I allow the corrector to launch

```
$ java RmiRegistry &
```

rather than

```
 $ java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=truststore -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=trustword RmiRegistry &
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add a new trusted authority to your Java Runtime Environment's `cacerts` file. This file is found `$JRE_HOME/lib/security/`. The default password is `changeit`.

Alternatively you can configure the properties on start up in your code:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "path to truststore");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "trustStorePassword");

System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "path to keystore");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "keyStorePassword)";
```

Comment: Do I need to put these lines at the start of every main ?